# How to walk a resource directory in a Python package?

Tags: python

I have a Python package with a resource folder being bundled into the build. The structure is similar to the following:

```
package
  - resources
    - subfolder
      - resource1.txt
    - resource2.txt
```

I know about `importlib_resources` and the standard version of that package, but I need an equivalent of `os.walk` for the resource directory (it could be heavily nested). Is there any way to do this? The `files()` and `contents()` methods don't seem to be able to achieve this.

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Ultimately, I'd like to read the contents of all of the files in the directory. The purpose is to copy them to another location.

Comment: so, a generator of file names will work?

Comment: Yes, as long as it will work for any Python package. Keep in mind the package could be zipped, so using `importlib` is fairly necessary (unless there's another solid alternative).

Answer (score 1):

After more research, I believe that at its current state, `importlib_resources` is not an options for this task. It has no way to traverse down directories. It may be available in a future release.

The easiest solution (albeit slow) is `pkg_resources` from the package `setuptools`. This package is not meant to be a run-time library, but for these purposes, we will make it one.

Here is a snippet for walking a package data directory:

```py
import pkg_resources

RESOURCE_ROOT = "mypackage"

def walk_data(base_dir: str, path: str = ""):
    for name in pkg_resources.resource_listdir(RESOURCE_ROOT, f"{base_dir}{path}"):
        path = f"{base_dir}{path}/{name}"
        if pkg_resources.resource_isdir(RESOURCE_ROOT, path):
            walk_data(base_dir, f"{path}/{name}")
        else:
            content = pkg_resources.resource_string(RESOURCE_ROOT, path)
            # Do something with the file content
```

Answer (score 0):

Sam Henry's answer is deprecated according to `setuptools`.
The new way for python 3.9+ is importlib.resources.files(package), which is traversable.